# caesar c# outputs numbers instead of shifted characters

Tags: c#, windows, caesar-cipher

Why does this program output numbers instead of shifted characters? I can't understand what is wrong in this code and what I forgot to add? Any answers appreciated.

```
static void Main(string[] args) 
{  
    string key;
    string text = string.Empty;
    int int_key;

    Console.Write("Enter a key: ");
    key = Console.ReadLine();

    if(key == "2") 
    {
        Console.Write("String you want to encrypt: ");
        text = Console.ReadLine();
    }
    else 
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Please enter a valid key: ");
    }

    int_key = int.Parse(key);

    for(int i = 0; i < text.Length; i++) 
    {
        if(char.IsUpper(text[i])) 
        {
            Console.Write("Encrypted string: " + (((char)text[i] + int_key) - 65)% 26 + 65);
        }
        else 
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Encrypted string: " + (((char)text[i] + int_key) - 97)% 26 + 97);
        }
    }

    Console.ReadKey();  
}
```

Comment: `(char)` is wrongly placed, that's why.

Comment: `text[i]` is already a `char`, and when you add a `char` and an `int`, the result is an `int`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Console.Write("Encrypted string: " + (((char)text[i] + int_key) - 65)% 26 + 65);
```

should more likely be:

```
Console.Write("Encrypted string: " + (char)(((text[i] + int_key) - 65)% 26 + 65));
//                                         |||_________________|     |         |
//                                         ||________________________|         |
//                                         |___________________________________|
```

Comment: Glad it helped and welcome to StackOverflow. Maybe you could read [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) :)